# Sequential Angular stateProvider resolves

Tags: angularjs, http

I need to perform router resolves in order. Meaning first run `ProfileLoaded` http call, when that finishes, run `Access` resolve. How can I do this?

```
$stateProvider.
    state('sign-up', {
        url : '/sign-up',
        templateUrl: '/html/pages/registration.html',
        controller: 'signupCtrl',
        resolve : {
            // Load profile first, then check if they are subscribed
            ProfileLoaded : ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
                return $rootScope.loadProfile();
            }],
            // Then check Access
            access: ['Access', function (Access) {
                return Access.isSubscribed();
            }]
        }
    })
```

Where `$rootScope.loadProfile();` is an AJAX `$http` request and, where `Access.isSubscribed` relies on the loaded profile to perform auth'ed routing.

The logical choice would be to put `access` as a callback in `loadProfile`, but don't want it to get messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$rootScope.loadProfile` returns a promise, simply add the required `resolve` property as a dependency, eg

```
access: ['Access', 'ProfileLoaded', function(Access, ProfileLoaded) {
    return Access.isSubscribed();
}]
```

See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$resolve#methods_resolve

> Dependencies of invocables are resolved (in this order of precedence)
>
> - from the specified locals
> - **from another invocable that is part of this $resolve call**
> - from an invocable that is inherited from a parent call to $resolve (or recursively from any ancestor $resolve of that parent).

and

> Invocables are invoked eagerly as soon as **all dependencies are available**.

Comment: So it'd be like access : `['Acces... function (Access, ProfileLoaded) { ProfileLoaded.then(function () return Access.isSubscribed() ...`

Comment: @Growler no, the resolver will wait until `ProfileLoaded` is resolved before attempting to resolve `Access` simply because you've listed the former as a dependency of the latter.

Comment: `ProfileLoaded` as you've described is not a service, I've only made it as `$rootScope.loadProfile = function ...` within the `run` method. Do I need to make this a service to inject as dependency?

Comment: @Growler I don't understand, it's right there in your `resolve` block ~ `resolve: { ProfileLoaded: [...]`. Did you read the linked documentation, specifically the parts I highlighted?